# Opengl C++: texture code textures all models with the same texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I created a class to hold my models information. I have to models rendering correctly and the textures properly wrapping, but for some reason if I have multiple models it will texture all of my models in just 1 texture as you can see in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvDQS.jpg

Any ideas why this might be happening?

This is my code:

```
struct BitMapFile
{
   int sizeX;
   int sizeY;
   unsigned char *data;
};


// Routine to read a bitmap file.
// Works only for uncompressed bmp files of 24-bit color.
BitMapFile *getBMPData(string filename)
{
   BitMapFile *bmp = new BitMapFile;
   unsigned int size, offset, headerSize;

   // Read input file name.
   ifstream infile(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);

   // Get the starting point of the image data.
   infile.seekg(10);
   infile.read((char *) &offset, 4); 

   // Get the header size of the bitmap.
   infile.read((char *) &headerSize,4);

   // Get width and height values in the bitmap header.
   infile.seekg(18);
   infile.read( (char *) &bmp->sizeX, 4);
   infile.read( (char *) &bmp->sizeY, 4);

   // Allocate buffer for the image.
   size = bmp->sizeX * bmp->sizeY * 24;
   bmp->data = new unsigned char[size];

   // Read bitmap data.
   infile.seekg(offset);
   infile.read((char *) bmp->data , size);

   // Reverse color from bgr to rgb.
   int temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 3)
   { 
      temp = bmp->data[i];
      bmp->data[i] = bmp->data[i+2];
      bmp->data[i+2] = temp;
   }

   return bmp;
}

class Model
{
public:
    Model(string modelFilename, string textureFilename);

   float getCenterX() { return m_CenterX; }
   float getCenterY() { return m_CenterY; }
   float getCenterZ() { return m_CenterZ; }
   void SetCenterX(float x) { m_CenterX = x; }
   void SetCenterY(float y) { m_CenterY = y; }
   void SetCenterZ(float z) { m_CenterZ = z; }

    void LoadTexture(string fileName);
    //load model function
    void Draw();
private:

    float m_CenterX, m_CenterY, m_CenterZ, m_Width, m_Height, m_Depth;

    string m_ModelFilename;

    int m_Texture;
        string m_TextureName;
};
Model::Model(string modelFilename, string textureFilename)
{
    m_ModelFilename = modelFilename;
    m_TextureName = textureFilename;

    //load model function//
    LoadTexture(m_TextureName);
}

void Model::LoadTexture(string TextureName)         
{
   // Local storage for bmp image data.
   BitMapFile *image[1];

        string filename = TextureName;
        filename.append(".bmp");

       // Load the texture.
       image[0] = getBMPData(filename);

       // Bind grass image to texture index[i]. 
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture); //makes room for our texture
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
       glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, //always GL_TEXTURE_2D
           0,                       //0 for now
           GL_RGB,                  //format opengl uses to read textures
           image[0]->sizeX,         //width
           image[0]->sizeY,         //height
           0,                       //the border of the image
           GL_RGB,                  //GL_RGB because pixels are stored in RGB format
           GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,        //GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE because pixels are stored as unsigned numbers
           image[0]->data);         //actual pixel data
}

void Model::Draw()
{
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(m_CenterX, m_CenterY, m_CenterZ);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        //my code for drawing the model to the screen. it isn't the problem so i removed it
        glEnd();

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glPopMatrix();
}

Model model;
Model model1;

// Drawing routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   glLoadIdentity();

   model.SetCenterX(0);
   model.SetCenterY(0); 
   model.SetCenterZ(12);
   model.Draw();

   model1.SetCenterX(12);
   model1.SetCenterY(10);
   model1.SetCenterZ(0);
   model1.Draw();

   glutSwapBuffers();
}

void setup(void) 
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 

    //model = Model("monkey.obj", "launch");
    model = Model("cube.obj", "launch");

    model1 = Model("cube.obj", "grass");

   // Specify how texture values combine with current surface color values.
   glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: as far as I know you didn't call your drawscene function at all.

Comment: Also, I don't see you calling `glGenTexture()` to get a texture id.

Comment: Obligatory comment: You are using deprecated fixed-function pipeline (`glBegin`, `glEnd` etc.). Consider moving to more modern OpenGL with shaders.

Comment: @Bot I didn't post my entire code because the rest isn't necessary. The problem is with my texture function. I left out the main that calls the setup, drawscene and the rest

Comment: @vesan how does glGenTexture() work? In the original code before I moved it over to a class had that in the setup function. 

What would you suggest for that? I definitely want to get away from glbegin/glend because I hear they are really bad. I tried using glBindVertexArray(), but it gave me an unhandled exception which I can't find a solution to.

Comment: First, we tell OpenGL to make room for the texture, by calling glGenTextures - Good tutorial -http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/textures/text.php

Comment: glGenTexture gives you an id which OpenGL uses to identify the texture. A good place to call it would be the beginning of `LoadTexture`, then store the number it gives you into `m_Texture`. Not sure if this is all you need to do to fix this, but it's a start.

Comment: @vesan That fixed it actually. After turning m_texture into an unsigned int arras of 1 it worked.  Thank you! That was a lot simpler than I thought. If you would like to set that as an answer and I will approve it. My only issue now is I don't know how to get vertex array working so I can get away from the fixed pipeline. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Bot When I was making this originally I was looking at that. yeah the glGenTexture was the reason it wasn't working. Thank you for the comment. Do you know about vertex arrays in opengl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not creating a texture id. You can do that using the `glGenTextures` function. In your case I would put it at the beginning of the `LoadTexture` method - just ask it for 1 texture id and save what it gives you back into `m_Texture`.

Remember that, like everything you create using `glGen*`, it should also be deleted when you're done with it using `glDelete*` (`glDeleteTextures` in this case).

Also, consider moving to more modern OpenGL with shaders and vertex arrays. This is a very broad topic, unfortunately. There are lots of tutorials and books available, I learned from [OpenGL Superbible](http://www.openglsuperbible.com/), though I hear that some people don't like it very much...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is what the issue was. Where would I put the delete code?

Comment: I have been looking, but I am having problems understanding it. if i try to cal the glGenVertexArrays it gives me an Unhandled exception. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I don't see any cleanup in your code. Usually you call delete when you're done with a particular resource (like a model or texture) and want to free memory. Think loading a new level, you delete stuff from the previous one if you don't need it anymore. I would really suggest reading some VAO tutorials. Or, if you have a speficic problem, posting a new question.